# Why is the rcpp function slow?

Tags: rcpp

I have made a simple function that sets a column reversal_indicator to "yes" if a value in the Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID is present anywhere in the column Accounting_Transaction_ID (i.e in other rows).Most entries in the Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID column are likely to be blank and therefore should be "no".

The dataframe is created from a 6gb csv file (assume approx 6 million rows) and is being processed on databricks.

I am not really sure why its taking such a long time

````
Rcpp::cppFunction('
std::vector<std::string>
reversals(DataFrame frame)
{
  std::vector<std::string> Accounting_Transaction_ID = as<std::vector<std::string> >(frame["BELNR"]);
  std::vector<std::string> Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID = as<std::vector<std::string> >(frame["STBLG"]);
  std::vector<std::string> ReversalIndicator(Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID.size()) ;

  if (Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID.size() == 0) {
    return ReversalIndicator;
  }
  int dfSize = Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < dfSize; ++i) {
    if (Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID[i] != "") {
      for (int j = 1; j < dfSize; ++j) {
        if(Accounting_Transaction_ID[j]== Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID[i]){
            ReversalIndicator[i]="Yes";
            break;
                                                                                }
         else if( (j== dfSize -1)  ){
                 ReversalIndicator[i]="No";
                                                                                                            }
                                      }
                                                    }
   else{
      ReversalIndicator[i]="No";
       }
                                  }
  return ReversalIndicator;
}

')```

```df$reversal=reversals(df)```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are traversing your data frame for every row of your data frame, i.e. you have something like 6m x 6m operations (O(N^2)). That can take quite a while. However, you can go from O(N^2) to O(N) at the expense of some memory. Without any sample data I cannot test this, so I am providing some pseudo code only:

```
create empty set data structure

for each row in df:
     Add Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID to set

for each row in df:
     if Accounting_Transaction_ID can be found in set
         ReversalIndicator = "Yes"
```

Comment: 'mio' is very German for million :)  I think one would just say 6m x 6m.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No, thank you for all the really good and helpful answers here!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Cool thanks.

I will give that a go.

In terms of speed how does the set method compare to performing a left join and then setting it to yes if the join column is not null?

Comment: @Tiger_Stripes Difficult to compare. It does make sense to try `data.table` and see if the performance is good enough.

Comment: @RalfStubner just wondering why checking each item against a set is not O(N^2) as surely for each time you check for an item in a set it has to iterate through the set even if its in memory?

I don't have a computer science background so might be a stupid question

Comment: @Tiger_Stripes The loop has O(N) complexity. The lookup in a set is either O(log(N)) for [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or O(1) for [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). This does not say anything about the constant factor in front, which is why it is important to benchmark the specific usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ralphs answer

Not sure if I need to allocate the set a size at the start though?

````
Rcpp::cppFunction('
std::vector<std::string> reversals(DataFrame frame)
{
  std::vector<std::string> Accounting_Transaction_ID = as<std::vector<std::string> >(frame["BELNR"]);
  std::vector<std::string> Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID = as<std::vector<std::string> >(frame["STBLG"]);
  std::vector<std::string> ReversalIndicator(Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID.size()) ;

  std::set<std::string> uniqueTransID;


  if (Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID.size() == 0) {
    return ReversalIndicator;
  }
  int dfSize = Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID.size();


 for (int i = 0; i < dfSize; ++i) {
    uniqueTransID.insert(Accounting_Transaction_ID[i]);
 }

  for (int i = 0; i < dfSize; ++i) {

      if (Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID[i] !=""){

             ReversalIndicator[i]="No";
             continue;
                                                         }
    if (uniqueTransID.find(Reversal_Accounting_Transaction_ID[i]) != uniqueTransID.end()) {

                 ReversalIndicator[i]="Yes";

                                      }

   else{
      ReversalIndicator[i]="No";

       }
                                  }
  return ReversalIndicator;
}


')```
````

Comment: You might consider using [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) together with C++11.